# Python: bytearray vs array

Tags: python, arrays

What is the difference between `array.array('B')` and `bytearray`?

```
from array import array

a = array('B', 'abc')
b = bytearray('abc')

a[0] = 100
b[0] = 'd'

print a
print b
```

Are there any memory or speed differences? What is the preferred use case of each one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bytearray` is the successor of Python 2.x's `string` type. It's basically the built-in byte array type. Unlike the original `string` type, it's mutable.

The `array` module, on the other hand, was created to create binary data structures to communicate with the outside world (for example, to read/write binary file formats).

Unlike `bytearray`, it supports all kinds of array elements. It's flexible.

So if you just need an array of bytes, `bytearray` should work fine. If you need flexible formats (say when the element type of the array needs to be determined at runtime), `array.array` is your friend.

Without looking at the code, my guess would be that `bytearray` is probably faster since it doesn't have to consider different element types. But it's possible that `array('B')` returns a `bytearray`.

Comment: I'd actually say `bytes` is the successor of Python 2.x's `str`, not `bytearray`.

Comment: That isn't really that accurate either. Python 2.x's `str` is like a mix of Python 3.x's str and bytes.

Comment: @Broseph: Well, `bytes` *is* a successor to 2.x's `str` targeting the "undifferentiated sequence of bytes" use case...

Answer (score 8):

`bytearray` has all the usual `str` methods. You can thing of it as a mutable `str` (bytes in Python3)

While array.array is geared to reading and writing files. 'B' is just a special case for array.array

You can see there is quite a difference looking at the `dir()` of each

```
>>> dir(bytearray)
['__add__', '__alloc__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__',
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append',
 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'extend',
 'find', 'fromhex', 'index', 'insert', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower',
 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans',
 'partition', 'pop', 'remove', 'replace', 'reverse', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust',
 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip',
 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>> dir(array)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__',
 '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', 
 '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append',
 'buffer_info', 'byteswap', 'count', 'extend', 'frombytes', 'fromfile',
 'fromlist', 'fromstring', 'fromunicode', 'index', 'insert', 'itemsize', 'pop',
 'remove', 'reverse', 'tobytes', 'tofile', 'tolist', 'tostring', 'tounicode',
 'typecode']
```

Answer (score 5):

[Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) is a good read which points to `array.array('B')` as being fast.  Using the `timing()` function from that essay does show that `array.array('B')` is faster than `bytearray()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from array import array
from struct import pack
from timeit import timeit
from time import clock

def timing(f, n, a):
    start = clock()
    for i in range(n):
        f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a); f(a)
    finish = clock()
    return '%s\t%f' % (f.__name__, finish - start)

def time_array(addr):
    return array('B', addr)

def time_bytearray(addr):
    return bytearray(addr)

def array_tostring(addr):
    return array('B', addr).tostring()

def str_bytearray(addr):
    return str(bytearray(addr))

def struct_pack(addr):
    return pack('4B', *addr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 10000
    addr = '192.168.4.2'
    addr = tuple([int(i) for i in addr.split('.')])
    print('\t\ttiming\t\tfunc\t\tno func')
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (timing(time_array, count, addr),
          timeit('time_array((192,168,4,2))', number=count, setup='from __main__ import time_array'),
          timeit("array('B', (192,168,4,2))", number=count, setup='from array import array')))
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (timing(time_bytearray, count, addr),
          timeit('time_bytearray((192,168,4,2))', number=count, setup='from __main__ import time_bytearray'),
          timeit('bytearray((192,168,4,2))', number=count)))
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (timing(array_tostring, count, addr),
          timeit('array_tostring((192,168,4,2))', number=count, setup='from __main__ import array_tostring'),
          timeit("array('B', (192,168,4,2)).tostring()", number=count, setup='from array import array')))
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (timing(str_bytearray, count, addr),
          timeit('str_bytearray((192,168,4,2))', number=count, setup='from __main__ import str_bytearray'),
          timeit('str(bytearray((192,168,4,2)))', number=count)))
    print('%s\t%s\t%s' % (timing(struct_pack, count, addr),
          timeit('struct_pack((192,168,4,2))', number=count, setup='from __main__ import struct_pack'),
          timeit("pack('4B', *(192,168,4,2))", number=count, setup='from struct import pack')))
```

The [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) measure actually shows `array.array('B')` is sometimes more than double the speed of `bytearray()`

I was interested specifically in the fastest way to pack an IP address into a four byte string for sorting. Looks like neither `str(bytearray(addr))` nor `array('B', addr).tostring()` come close to the speed of `pack('4B', *addr)`.

Comment: I believe packing an IP address to int would actually be even faster for sorting.

Comment: @LieRyan: Wouldn't that tend to either run into sign issues or involve multiple-precision arithmetic, though?

Answer (score 2):

From my test, both used amostly **same size of memory** but the speed of bytearry is **1.5 times** of array when I create a **large buffer to read and write.**

```
from array import array
from time import time

s = time()

"""
map = array('B')
for i in xrange(256**4/8):
        map.append(0)
"""

#bytearray
map = bytearray()
for i in xrange(256**4/8):
        map.append(0)
print "init:", time() - s
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about your test workloads?

Comment: @SamB  btw, are you a robot?

Comment: No, but I was going through one of the review queues -- probably the "late answers" one.  Anyway, the number is certainly a lot more meaningful now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One difference that has not been mentioned is that the end user string representations differs for bytearrays and arrays with type `'b'`.

```
>>> import array
>>> arr = array.array('b', [104, 105])
>>> byte_arr = bytearray([104, 105])
>>> print(arr)
array('b', [104, 105])
>>> print(byte_arr)
bytearray(b'hi')
```

This goes in line with the notion that `bytearray` is supposed to be Python3's (mutable) "raw" string type and assumes its data represents characters.

edit:

Another notable difference is that `array.array` has a `tofile` method for efficiently dumping data to a file which `bytearray` and `bytes` lack.

Answer (score -2):

You almost never need to use `array.array` module yourself. It's usually used for creating binary data for binary file format or protocol, like the `struct` module.

`bytearray` is usually used for dealing with encoded text (e.g. utf-8, ascii, etc), as opposed to Python 3's `str()` or Python 2's `unicode()` which is used for Unicode text.

Most of the time, you should be using either str() when dealing with text, or list and tuple when you need a collection of items, including numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it is a @Lie. array.array is always useful whenever you need memory-efficient representation of a group of data.

Comment: @Iceberg: yeah, but most of the time you'd use tuple or list, or sometimes numpy. Rarely it is necessary or a good idea to use `array.array()`.

Comment: `bytes` is used for dealing with encoded text, similar to Python 2's str type. `bytearray` is a mutable version of `bytes`.